# Overriding a variable in Java?

Tags: java

I have to implement class Vase which has different types of flowers. Every type of flower has specified weight.

```
public class Vase {

    int weight=0;
    void Put (Flower a)
    {
    weight+=a.w;
    }
    void Remove (Flower a)
    {
    weight-=a.w;
    }
    int getTotalPrice()
    {
        return weight;
    }
}

public abstract class Flower {
    int w =10;
}

public class Rose  extends Flower{
    int w =3;
}

public class Tulip  extends Flower{
    int w =1;
}
```

I am obliged to use inheritance. Then when i do this:

```
Vase vase1= new Vase();
Rose rose1=new Rose();
Rose rose2=new Rose();
Tulip tulip1=new Tulip();
firstv.Put(rose1);
firstv.Put(rose2);
firstv.Put(tulip1);
System.out.println(vase1.getTotalPrice());
```

I get 30 not 7? How to change the code to make getTotalPrice count the weight of Rose not Flower?

Comment: I strongly recommend you to follow up tutorials about Java first, preferably the official Oracle Trails they provide on their website.

Comment: You could just add a constructor to the children that sets `w`

Answer (score 0):

Java only allows methods to be overridden. You'll have to add an `int getWeight()` method to the `Flower` class, and override that.

Answer (score 0):

Variables can not be overridden in Java. So each has it's own instance of the variable in your case.

The nice thing to do would be to create a function `getWeight()`, make it abstract, then the subclasses must implement it with their own values.

Comment: Each also has its own method which can be explicitly called. It might be more helpful to point the OP to shadowing and the modelling of instance variables being overriden with the introduction of a subclass getter for that instance variable.